# Java XML DTD validation

Tags: xml

How can I validate an XML document against a DTD file which only my application knows about. So that the XML document which should be validated does not contain the DOCTYPE declaration which specifies the .dtd file. I need this in Java.
Here is an example:
The xml file to be validated:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" ?>
<Employee>
  <Emp_Id> E-001 </Emp_Id>
  <Emp_Name> Vinod </Emp_Name>
  <Emp_E-mail> Vinod1@yahoo.com </Emp_E-mail>
</Employee>
```

The .dtd file from my application:

```
<!ELEMENT Employee (Emp_Id, Emp_Name, Emp_E-mail)>
<!ELEMENT Emp_Id (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Emp_Name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Emp_E-mail (#PCDATA)>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the Java Documentation - [API for validation of XML documents](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/package-summary.html)

> SUMMARY:This package provides an API
>   for validation of XML documents.
>   Validation is the process of verifying
>   that an XML document is an instance of
>   a specified XML schema. An XML schema
>   defines the content model (also called
>   a grammar or vocabulary) that its
>   instance documents will represent.

Example:

```
Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(new FileInputStream("xmlDoc.xml"));
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(xmlDocument);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.DOCTYPE_SYSTEM, "xmlDoc.dtd");
transformer.transform(source, result);
```