# Validation of an xml document using a dtd document

Tags: xml, dtd

I'm new to XML. I'm confused how a DTD document validates an XML document. Below is my code and please correct me if I am wrong.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>

<!DOCTYPE note  
[
<!ELEMENT note (to,from,heading,body)>
<!ELEMENT to (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT from (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT heading (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT body (#PCDATA)>
]>

<note>
<to>Tove</to>

<rom>Jani</rom> // Here i've miss-spelled the tag <from> but still not getting error

<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body> 
</note>
```

I know that a DTD is used to validate the XML data. There is an element name `<form>`. I've just changed the spelling of `<form>` to `<rom>` but still did not get any error message in my browser. I'm stuck at this point.

Comment: I think most browsers are not meant to validate XML, but to render markup as good as possible. I would suggest to use an external tool for validation. For example I just found http://www.xmlvalidation.com to come handy.

Comment: so what is the best method if someone wants send and receive data in the form of XML. How that data will be validated with DTD

Comment: I don't know exactly what you meant by send/receive, but apparently you will need to validate the XML file against the DTD on the server side (if there is a server involved). Here is an example of XML validation that uses Java: [XML Validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332686/java-xml-dtd-validation).

Comment: DTD is not used as often as it used to be. Mostly we use XML Schema (XSD) to validate XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the XML community.

You will need to find and use a validating parser for your XML; if you want to use a Web browser, you may be disappointed.  Older versions of Internet Explorer validate XML against a DTD by default; newer versions don't (but I believe that you can configure them to do so if you can figure out how).  Mozilla-based browsers don't have a validating XML parser at all.

Most people who use XML seriously end up using XML-specific tools for validation.  Among my favorites for command-line validation are

- xmllint (the command-line interface to libxml2, which is part of the Gnome project but is also usable outside Gnome)
- rxp (by Richard Tobin of the University of Edinburgh)
- Xerces J, Xerces C (these are Apache projects)

There are also XML-aware editors which offer integrated validation from within the editor (sometimes from your choice of several parsers).

Comment: @Sperberg It would have been great if you would have mentioned which XML-aware editors offer integrated validation.